# Is it possible to confine SSH users to a new mount namespace on Login?

Tags: linux, ssh, systemd, namespaces, multi-tenancy

Users logging into our shared servers over SSH currently always enter into the root mount namespace, which for example allows all users to see the same `/var/tmp` directory, making it a contended resource which is shared by all users (and the root filesystem, if /var/tmp isn't a unique filesystem).

Using systemd, it's trivial to configure a Service (or instance of a service) to a unique mount namespace, for example to give them a private (tmpfs) /var/tmp which is unique to that service/session.

Is there a good way to do something similar for users - so that for example, on login a user will have a new mount namespace setup where their `/var/tmp` is actually (for example) a symlink to `/srv/vartempfs/$UID`? I guess this would have to be a single mount namespace per user, in order to ensure that two sessions to the same server would share the same "/var/tmp".

Comment: The standard [PAM subsystem](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam) includes a [pam_namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_namespace.8.html) module that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is extremely easy, especially for /var/tmp. On RHEL-derived systems such as CentOS 7, this can be achieved by simply uncommenting a line in `/etc/security/namespace.conf`:

```
# /etc/security/namespace.conf
#
# See /usr/share/doc/pam-*/txts/README.pam_namespace for more information.
#
# Uncommenting the following three lines will polyinstantiate
# /tmp, /var/tmp and user's home directories. /tmp and /var/tmp will
# be polyinstantiated based on the MLS level part of the security context as well as user
# name, Polyinstantion will not be performed for user root and adm for directories
# /tmp and /var/tmp, whereas home directories will be polyinstantiated for all users.
# The user name and context is appended to the instance prefix.
#
# Note that instance directories do not have to reside inside the
# polyinstantiated directory. In the examples below, instances of /tmp
# will be created in /tmp-inst directory, where as instances of /var/tmp
# and users home directories will reside within the directories that
# are being polyinstantiated.
#
# Instance parent directories must exist for the polyinstantiation
# mechanism to work. By default, they should be created with the mode
# of 000. pam_namespace module will enforce this mode unless it
# is explicitly called with an argument to ignore the mode of the
# instance parent. System administrators should use this argument with
# caution, as it will reduce security and isolation achieved by
# polyinstantiation.
#
#/tmp     /tmp-inst/        level      root,adm
#/var/tmp /var/tmp/tmp-inst/    level      root,adm
#$HOME    $HOME/$USER.inst/     level
```

Thanks for [@larsks](https://serverfault.com/users/27515/larsks) for pointing me at `pam_namespace`.

Comment: Worth noting that polyinstantiation of `/tmp` currently breaks `ssh`'s X11 forwarding because any remote session connecting back to an isolated `ssh` client's `/tmp/.X11-unix/X${DISPLAY#*:}` socket fails. Root owns the sockets in `/tmp/.X11-unix` to they're in `/tmp` instead of `/tmp-inst/$USER` or however you've configured it.

Comment: Does pam_namespace rely on having SELinux enabled and in enforcing mode?

Comment: Hi Troels, I feel like it'd be quicker to consult [the docs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_namespace), but no, I don't believe so - as there is an option which _can_ be set to require SELinux to be enabled, implying that it works without.